# Can't install apps from TestFlight after updating XCode to 7.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, testflight

- Previous TestFlight builds worked fine and I could download them fine
- I upgraded to the latest version of XCode from the App store
- I archived and uploaded a build just fine
- After it was done with beta review, I tried to download it from TestFlight and it failed to download
- I used configurator to inspect the error and it came up with `Failed to verify code signature of...` and `The executable was signed with invalid entitlements`.
- I checked all my provisioning profiles and they are correct
- I do have the `beta-reports-active = 1` entitlement when i look at the summary of the archive
- When the build is uploaded to iTunes connect and processing, I see this warning: `Some builds are missing the beta entitlement, or were uploaded with a beta version of Xcode, and cannot be tested.`
  [image: Beta error]
- What is weird though is my app passes beta review.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using build number `1` I changed it to something like `6`. E.g. `1.0.6 (6)`. Also under `Code Signing Identity` I put IOS Developer for every entry and Provisioning Profile as `Automatic`. I no longer get the issue in the screenshot. Will see if it also lets me download the build, but need to wait for beta review.